# Asp.net MVC repopulate form without using html helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

If i submit the form without filling some of the mandatory fields, when the page reloads again with errors, the fields that were filled out retain their values, but only if I use html helpers like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) </p>
    <p>Your email: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)</p>
    <p>Your phone: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone)</p>
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WillAttend, new[] {

        <input          new SelectListItem() {
                            Text = "Yes, I'll be there",
                            Value = bool.TrueString},
                        new SelectListItem() {
                            Text = "No, I can't come",
                            Value = bool.FalseString}
                        }, "Choose an option")
    </p> type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" />
}
```

But I want to use regular html and not helpers like so (and then the values aren't remembered):

```
<form action="/Home/RsvpForm" method="post">
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>
        Your name:
        <input type="text" name="Name" value="" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Your email:
        <input type="text" name="Email" value="" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Your phone:
        <input type="text" name="Phone" value="" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Will you attend?
        <select name="WillAttend">
            <option value="">Choose an option</option>
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

So how can I make the form remember the correctly entered values without using html helpers, is it possible?

**EDIT: the model and and the whole view**

GuestResponse model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PartyInvites.Models
{
    public class GuestResponse
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Enter name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter phone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Specify")]
        public bool? WillAttend { get; set; }



    }
}
```

The whole view:

```
@model PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>RsvpForm</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/Home/RsvpForm" method="post">
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <p>
            Your name:
            <input type="text" name="Name" value="" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Your email:
            <input type="text" name="Email" value="" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Your phone:
            <input type="text" name="Phone" value="" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Will you attend?
            <select name="WillAttend">
                <option value="">Choose an option</option>
                <option value="true">Yes</option>
                <option value="false">No</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you use HTML helpers how does HTML look like? Easy way to convert from helpers to plain HTML is to run code with helpers and see how resulting HTML look like and use that HTML to construct your view ...

Comment: So what you are saying is that you want to write 2 or 3 times as much code as necessary and you don't want true 2-way model binding to your model and you don't want client side validation or any of the other features built in to MVC. Why?

Comment: No, I am not saying that. And you downvoted my Q because I don't want to use html helpers? :D and I am using two-way data binding regardless,.it's just the html helpers are a hassle to me.

Comment: No you are not using 2-way model binding. For example when you return the view from a POST method due to `ModelState` errors, the html helpers correctly use the `AttemptedValue` property of `ModelState`

Comment: anyway, you downvoted my Q because I don't want to use html helpers?

Comment: I down voted your question for 2 reasons. (1) The question is not useful - your basically asking how do I make MVC not work the way it is designed to, and (2) Your code has `<<input type="text" name="Phone" value="@Model.Phone" />` which will display the value of property `Phone` so if its not, then the question is unclear (you have not included the relevant code)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular html, just set the value of input text, to receive your model.property like:

```
<input type="text" name="Phone" value="@Model.Phone" />
```

Comment: that gives an error, 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: it is added like so: @model PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse

Comment: @OlliccaMindstorm don't forget that your model can be passed in as null. I would try to prevent that if at all possible, but if you can't, you can always check for a null model before you render the properties.

Comment: @OlliccaMindstorm You could even potentially make a "default" model at the top if you find that is null. Before you call properties, just call this: @{ if (Model == null) { Model = new PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse(); } }

Comment: @ZacharyDow I am new to asp and c#, what exactly do I need to put inside the input's value? I tried value="@if (Model.Phone == null) @Model.Phone" but it gives an error.

Comment: @OlliccaMindstorm The phone isn't the issue, it's the Model. Your model has nothing in it (null). Null has no concept of a phone number, because it is the absence of an object. That is why you are getting errors trying to access Phone out of nothing. -

It's not preferable, but you can write something like this on every line: @(Model.Phone != null ? Model.Phone : "")
My example above is trying to help you prevent the clutter of this. In case you are wondering what it means, [it's just a shorthand if statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @ZacharyDow I know what a shorthand if statement is, I just don't know asp.net and razor. The shorthand gives the same error as before, and I tried using the code you gave above but it gives a different error: Model' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: @olliccamindstorm I'm so sorry! I goofed @(Model != null ? Model.Phone : "")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84689/discussion-between-zachary-dow-and-ollicca-mindstorm).

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
@model your_model 

 <form action="/Home/RsvpForm" method="post">
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<p>
    Your name:
    <input type="text" name="Name" value="@Model.Name" />
</p>
<p>
    Your email:
    <input type="text" name="Email" value="@Model.Email" />
</p>
<p>
    Your phone:
    <input type="text" name="Phone" value="@Model.Phone" />
</p>
<p>
    Will you attend?
    <select name="WillAttend">
        <option value="">Choose an option</option>
        <option value="true">Yes</option>
        <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>
</p>
<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: the model binding is added but i still get the error -  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  In the model, for example Phone is set like so: public string Phone { get; set; } - could that maybe be the problem?

Comment: what is the name of your model class? and can you also post your model binding? If you don't mind sharing ...

Comment: I added the whole code for both the model and the view, thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @EmmanuelN I used this but when i want to display empty view and from controller i use `return View();` it give me error because model is null,How should i resolve this? is there better solution than `@(Model != null ? Model.Phone : "")`

Answer (score 1):

Your model is coming in as null. Null has no concept of a phone number, because it is the absence of an object. That is why you are getting errors trying to access Phone out of nothing. You need to handle the null case for each time you are trying to access a property of the Model.

You can use this for your properties:

```
@(Model != null ? Model.Phone : "")
```

Or, if you are able to use C#6 syntax, feel free to use this:

```
@Model?.Phone
```